# Axios returning 401 if Authorization header is set through state or context variable in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, axios

I'm working on React Native, in which the axios returns post details from my express api. I use jwt to authenticate user request. The JWT token is in state variable and it is passed to header authorization value. But it works only on first load, When I try to reload the app it shows [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401] If I try to add data to axios it return Network error. I confirmed my API is fine through Postman, It works fine and returns data. To recheck again, I tried to hard coded to header value, it works fine. But If I pass from state or context variable it throws the 401 error. Again checked with CORS and everything on Express it is fine. I don't know what's happening. Help me with it.

BASE_API_URL = http://192.168.1.2:3000
The above URL runs Express

With state variable it dosen't work

```
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    //console.log(userGlobalToken)
    await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${BASE_API_URL}/posts/all`,
      headers: {
        'Get-Auth': userJwtToken
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setPostsData(response.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => {
        setPostLoading(false)
        setRefreshing(false)
      })
  }
```

This works fine!

```
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    //console.log(userGlobalToken)
    await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${BASE_API_URL}/posts/all`,
      headers: {
        'Get-Auth': "<jwt token here>"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setPostsData(response.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => {
        setPostLoading(false)
        setRefreshing(false)
      })
  }
```

If you still think it is the problem with express, I checked with AJAX in normal web it worked fine. I console logged to check if the token exist in state variable and it is set. I also checked with other axios requests in which without authorization it throws network error or 404.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the value of `userJwtToken`?
Try logging it inside fetchPost.

Comment: Yeah, I logged it inside and I figured it out. I used SecureStore to store the Token, but on retrieve it was still a JSON string that I need to parse. The problem was double quotes. Thanks for your comment. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

401 error :
expired or invalid your userJwtToken.
401 is "Unauthorized".
after along what time   ​your authurization auto code   change ?

Comment: I know what is 401 error. But it should be working fine as I asked in the question. I actually figured it out and Thanks for your reply!